# Root GT-I9305 running Android 4.4.4 Build Version KTU84P.I9305XXUFNI3

Tags: rooting

I want to root Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE GT-I9305 running Android 4.4.4 Build Version KTU84P.I9305XXUFNI3.Can you please help

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to root the i9305. 2 ways i recommend are to use chainfire's method (bit complex) or framaroot (easiest) To do all this,first have the USB debugging enabled. To do so,go to settings and navigate to "About Device". Keep pressing the build number 6 or 7 times til its says developer settings have been enabled. Go back and you will see "Developer Options" Open the developer options and check the USB debugging option.

#### Framaroot

- [download framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)
- Allow the framaroot downloaded app to be installed when there is a prompt to whether or not to install apps from unknown sources.
- Open the app and select Aragorn
- Reboot and you shall have the device rooted.
- Update the supersus from the google play store, then open the Supersu app and update the binary. It will ask if you want to disable knox,select yes.

#### Chainfire's CF-Auto-Root

- [download CF-Auto-Root](http://download.chainfire.eu/232/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-m3-m3zh-gti9305.zip) and extract to a folder.
- Turn phone off.
- Press the volume down,home screen button together. Then while pressing those 2, press the lock key and it will ask to whether reboot or go into download mode.
- Take note rooting voids warranty. Press volume down to continue to download mode.
- Now open the extracted folder and open odin. Select PDA and select the CF AutoRoot MD5 file. Connect phone via usb and lick start. It will do everything and reboot.
- Update the supersu from the google play store, then open the Supersu app and update the binary. It will ask if you want to disable knox,select yes.
- Then reboot and its fully rooted.

Always consider donating to the developer of framaroot and supersu (chainfire).

Comment: Framaroot does not work with **Android 4.4.4** on S3 GT-I9305. Note that this device is more likely to have Android 4.3, so most root methods would focus on exploits available in that. The asker asked for a root method that uses exploits available in 4.4.4. *(My build number is KTU84P.I9305XXUFOE1)*

Comment: The correct version of CF-Auto-Root for Android **4.4.4** on m3xx device is [here](https://download.chainfire.eu/729/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-m3-m3xx-gti9305.zip). The link in the answer points to the version for Android 4.1.1 on m3zh device. Don't use that. The rest of the instructions are fine, although I didn't get any prompt to update the binary when I opened SuperSU app. I have successfully rooted my I9305 running 4.4.4.

Comment: `Can't open specified file` error on Odin :-(

Comment: `Can't open specified file` error on Odin, solved on removing the "re-partition" flag and it worked

Comment: stuck on `establishing connection` solved by removing battery and reboot on download mode

Answer (score 2):

The following is the standard root method for most Samsung devices, using **Chainfire's Auto-Root**.

**Prerequisites**:

- Download and install appropriate [USB drivers](http://www.droidviews.com/android-usb-drivers-samsung-motorola-sony-lg-zte-htc-asus-huawei-acer/).
- Enable USB Debugging.

  - Go to `Settings > About Phone > Tap on Build Number until message appears.
  - Now go to Developer Options and enable USB Debugging.
- Backup your Apps, Contacts, Logs, Messages and Settings using [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) or a third party app like [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en).
- Download CF-Auto-Root package (file: [CF-Auto-Root-m3-m3zh-gti9305.zip](http://download.chainfire.eu/232/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-m3-m3zh-gti9305.zip))

**Rooting Process**:

- Extract CF-Auto-Root-m3-m3zh-gti9305.zip to your desktop.
- Switch off your device. Press Volume Down, Home and Power button altogether until you see the warning triangle. Now press the Volume Up button to enter into Download Mode.
- Now connect your device to the PC via USB cable.
- Run Odin3 v3.07.exe with Administrator privileges.
- You will see the COM port number in the ID: COM box, which means the connection has been established successfully.
- In the Odin window, click on the PDA button (or AP for older version) and select the CF-Auto-Root-m3-m3zh-gti9305.tar.md5
- Make sure Auto-Reboot and F.Reset Time are checked.
- Click on the Start button to initiate the process and observe the on-going process in the Message screen on the bottom-left of the Odin window.
- Once the process is complete, you will be indicated by a PASS message.

To verify if your device has been successfully rooted, install [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) and then update SuperSU binaries.